# Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node', except it didn't fail?

Tags: javascript, html

I get this error when using `.replaceChild()`, although I also got a similar one when I was using `.outerHTML` as well. The error only pops up when running `labelSubmit()`; running `labelFocusLost()` directly throws no error. The frustrating thing is that it doesn't fail to replace. It actually works, but Chrome is throwing an error anyways. It is technically functional so if this is just a strange Chrome bug it's not a big deal but I'd really prefer to have zero errors in my log if possible.

```js
function labelSubmit(literal) {
    const key  = event.key.toLowerCase()
    const exit = key == "escape" || key == "enter"

    if (exit) { labelFocusLost(literal) }
}

function labelFocusLost(literal) {
    const param   = literal.split(":")
    const target  = event.target
    const escaped = false

    const prev = {
        index: param[0],
        choice: param[1],
        name: target.value.toLowerCase() || param[2]
    }

    const label = `<label for="tabs-${prev.index}" class="default-text radio-label button ${prev.choice}" onpointerup="tabClick()">${escaped ? param[2] : prev.name}</label>`

    target.parentNode.parentNode.replaceChild(textToHTML(label), target.parentNode)
    //target.parentElement.outerHTML = label
}
```

```
<div id="tabs" class="grid-tabs debug">
    <input id="tabs-0" type="radio" name="tabs" class="no-display" checked="">
        <div class="default-text input-wrapper">
            <span class="clear input-measure">defaualt tab</span>
            <input maxlength="15" class="clear default-text input" placeholder="input new name here" value="defaualt tab" oninput="labelInput('input new name here')" onkeydown="labelSubmit('0:button-choice:defaualt tab')" onfocusout="labelFocusLost('0:button-choice:defaualt tab')" style="width: 113px;">
        </div>
    <input id="tabs-1" type="radio" name="tabs" class="no-display" />
        <label for="tabs-1" class="default-text radio-label button" onpointerup="tabClick()">default tab</label>
    <button data-choice="" class="clear default-text button" onclick="addTab()">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You're trying to use `event` but you're not sending it into your functions.

Comment: Turns out that wasn't what it was. Running `labelFocusLost()` would remove the element from the DOM. However, once the element was gone, focus would also be lost on the element, so `labelFocusLost()` would trigger again. Except, there would no longer be an element to remove. The fix for this was pretty simple; instead of running `labelFocusLost()`, simply force the element to lose focus by using `.blur()`, which would in turn run `labelFocusLost()` and remove the element. Since focus had already been removed, it wouldn't run a second time.

Answer (score 0):

@Batu.Khan pointed me in the right direction accidentally, so I'm posting the solution here.

> Turns out that wasn't what it was. Running `labelFocusLost()` would
>   remove the element from the DOM. However, once the element was gone,
>   focus would also be lost on the element, so `labelFocusLost()` would
>   trigger again. Except, there would no longer be an element to remove.
>   The fix for this was pretty simple; instead of running
>   `labelFocusLost()`, simply force the element to lose focus by using
>   `.blur()`, which would in turn run `labelFocusLost()` and remove the
>   element. Since focus had already been removed, it wouldn't run a
>   second time.

This fix was ultimately just

```js
if (exit) { event.target.blur() }
```